# C++ template : no matching function for call

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code

```
template <typename T, T one>
T exponentiel(T val, unsigned n) {
    T result = one;
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        result = result * val;

    return result;
}

int main(void) {

    double d = exponentiel<double,1.0>(2.0f,3);

    cout << d << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler tells me this
no matching function for call to 'exponentiel(float, int)'

Why?

What's strange is that exponentiel works with int.

Comment: It's spelled 'exponential', by the way.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is with the `T one` and the `1.0` in the template argument list.

You can't have a nontype template parameter of a floating point type and you can't pass a floating point value as a template argument.  It's just not allowed (to the best of my knowledge, there's no really good reason why it's not allowed).

g++'s error message here is rather unhelpful.  Visual C++ 2010 reports the following on the line where the template is used in `main`:

```
error C2993: 'double' : illegal type for non-type template parameter 'one'
```

[Comeau Online](http://comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) reports:

```
line 13: error: expression must have integral or enum type
    double d = exponentiel<double,1.0>(2.0f,3);
                                  ^

line 2: error: floating-point template parameter is nonstandard
    template <typename T, T one>
                          ^
```

Comment: +1. And to go further, the specific error comes up because as James said the template function instantiation you give is invalid. Therefore, the function you're trying to call is never brought into existence. Therefore, there is no matching function for the call.

Comment: "no really good reason why [float parameters] not allowed" with simplistic compiler implementation, epsilon errors result in many template instantiations for what seems superficially like one value.  Specialisations might fail to terminate recursion as expected.  Even with the same compiler version, these things might be CPU model dependent, CPU dependent etc. - making it hard to use libraries and objects compiled on another machine.  Walter Bright allows it in D; the C++ community's much less resilient against post-facto tweaks.  Are these your "not good" reasons?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Tony:  I reject outright the notion of a simplistic C++ compiler implementation :-)  A conforming implementation already has to be able to perform floating point computations in constant expressions.  I don't think it's correct to say that the C++ community doesn't like tweaks; certainly _breaking tweaks_ are not liked, but in general, I think people want the language to improve.

Comment: Vandevoorde and Josuttis state in _C++ Templates:  The Complete Guide_, "Not being able to use floating-point literals as template arguments has historical reasons.  Because there are no serious technical challenges, this may be supported in future versions of C++"  (page 40).  [Note that they are not supported in C++0x.]

Comment: I see there's discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800867/templatefloating-point-non-type - not much to add.  Cheers.