# How do i specialize this class template for std::string?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am writing a TMP to count the number of elements passed to a `struct` as template parameters using variadic templates. This is my code:

```
template<class T, T... t>
struct count;

template<class T, T h, T... t> 
struct count<T, h, t...>{
 static const int value = 1 + count<T, t...>::value;
};

template<class T>
struct count<T>{
 static const int value = 0;
};

template<>
struct count<std::string, std::string h, std::string... l>{
 static const int value = 1 + count<std::string, l...>::value;
};

template<>
struct count<std::string>{
 static const int value = 0;
};

int main(){
 std::cout << count<int, 10,22,33,44,56>::value << '\n';
 std::cout << count<bool, true, false>::value << '\n';
 std::cout << count<std::string, "some">::value << '\n';
 return 0;
```

}

I get an error on the third instantiation of `count` with `std::string` because `g++ 4.7` tells me `error: ‘class std::basic_string<char>’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter`. Any workaround for this?

Comment: What about the variadic `sizeof...`? Also, class-types cannot appear as non-type template arguments, nor can string literals.

Comment: `sizeof...` just made the specializations disappear. Thank you. But is there a different way for what i am trying to achieve?

Comment: What *are* you trying to achieve? (I don't mean "what do you think is the solution", but really what your ultimate problem is.)

Comment: I am reading Milewski's blog: http://bartoszmilewski.com/2009/10/21/what-does-haskell-have-to-do-with-c/ and trying to emulate what he did in it but not for types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the type `std::string` but the literal `"some"` in your call

```
std::cout << count<std::string, "some">::value << '\n';
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible to pass a string or floating point literal to a template as is also written [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033112/1450656) or [in that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800947/1450656).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to disappoint you, but there's no way around this. Non-type template parameters can only be primitive types such as:

- integral or enumeration
- pointer to object or pointer to function
- reference to object or reference to function
- pointer to member

`std::string` or other types simply don't work there.

Comment: Well, there is `boost::mpl::string` which is a perfectly fine template parameter.