# Template specialization works with int and fails with double as a class

Tags: c++, templates

I hava a following simple template:

```
template<class T, T N>
bool VerifyGT(T value) {
  return value > N;
}

bool (*test1)(int) = &VerifyGE< int, (int) 0>;  // (1)
bool (*test2)(double) = &VerifyGE< double, (double) 0.0>;  // (2)
```

When compiling: test1 initialization succeeds, test2 fails with "doesn not match required type". Any ideas?

Comment: non-type template parameters have to be intergal types or enumerations.

Comment: Same problem and some discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800867/templatefloating-point-non-type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Non-type template arguments cannot be of floating-point type. Only integral types, enumerations, pointers and references are allowed.

Comment: i hope you don't just copied the answer from juanchopanza's comment :D otherwise i'll take back my +1.

Comment: @itwasntpete The comment wasn't loaded when I posted the answer. And it doesn't list pointers/refs.